# Absolute position element on equal height columns - how?

Tags: css

Here's what I can't do by any means, **using only CSS**:

Columns should have equal heights.
And, on a given column, a absolute positioned element should be present relative to that column:

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="inner">
  <div class="column">
   <img src="http://www.english3.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/DFI-Logo-300px-X-200px.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="column info">
   <p>Some text here yeah :).</p>
   <p>Some text here yeah :)</p>
   <p>Some text here yeah :)</p>
   <a class="link" href="#">I should be absolute.</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**THE CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

/*added */
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.column {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:red;
}

.column img {
  max-width:100%;  
  display: block;
 }

.info {
    background-color: blue;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.link {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 3%;
    color: yellow;
}
```

**Fiddle to play:**

Here's the try with table-cell; and a relative inner container:
http://jsfiddle.net/BuuFv/98/

## TRIES AND FRUSTRATIONS:

### 1) - Display table

For equal heights I can't pull this out, due to FF issues.

**Tried with an extra relative parent container**

But left image doesn't shrink according to it's container on FF.

**Tried giving height: 100%**

http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute
   But didn't work either, the image doesn't shrink or expands using max-width;

### 2 - Huge positive padding and negative margin values

Will not work, because the absolute positioned element will not stay in place.

### 3 - Faux Columns

Seems to be of any help, due to the fact that, we are not playing with solid background colours, and we have an image on the left column instead.

## A picture:

[image: The intended result seems quite simple to archieve]

Any help, please?

Comment: Could you make a simple picture in MSPAINT just to show me how exactly u want the output to be? I cannot image it right now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
On this case, adding an extra relative container with position relative attribute (`.inner`), did the trick.

2)
The fact that the image didn't shrink or grow on FF was because it wasn't considering the `max-width` declaration as it should.

Fix:

```
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed; /* <<-- ADD */
}
```

the `table-layout fixed` algorithm made Firefox recognize the `max-width` in the cell and this let the image shrink.

*Credits on this solution should be shared with Paul O'B.*

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/BuuFv/75/

You can try changing the link from absolute positioned to another table-cell. Not 100% on your use case but it seems to accomplish what you are asking.

```
.link {
    height:100px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK - That doesn't seem to properly work on FF. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it http://jsfiddle.net/E6UDD/

So basically, uncoment padding and negative margin hack, and add the height of the column to be the same amount.

Then, add relative positioning to the `.column`.

Then, position of the absolute positioned link should be `top: 50%` to have it at the very bottom, or 44% to mimic the 3% you originally indended.

Comment: The height is not desirable. I've updated my question with a sample image, for proper understanding of the intended result. Thanks.

Comment: can given html structure be changed?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, because that will require javascript to play a role, and the point was to make this layout as responsive as possible using css only. I believe that a solution using `display table` and a `relative container` may work, and I will give a try on that later today.

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/ra4fM/)

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    outline:1px solid red;
    height:auto;
}
.column {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
}
.column img {
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:30px;
    min-height:20px;
}
.info {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    background-color: blue;
}
.link {
    clear:left;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This breaks if you add any content to the right col - http://jsfiddle.net/ra4fM/1/